# Keep getting the error MissingTranslationId

Tags: reactjs, localization

> **Note:** This question is exclusively related to the library
>   `react-localize-redux` but I cannot create a tag for it yet.

I want to use the allLanguages format. So I created a .json file named `global.json` that looks like this:

```
{
    "header": {
        "toggleNavigation": [
            "Cambiar navegación",
            "Toggle navigation"
        ],
        "home": [
            "Inicio",
            "Home"
        ],
        "company": [
            "Compañía",
            "Company"
        ]
    }
}
```

I decided to implement everything in my Root component as follows:

```
...
import allTranslations from "../translations/global.json";
...

class Root extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props.initialize({
      languages: [
        { name: "Spanish", code: "es" },
        { name: "English", code: "en" }
      ],
      translation: allTranslations,
      options: {
        renderToStaticMarkup
      }
    });

    this.props.addTranslation(allTranslations); // just to make sure it's loading the json dictionary

    this.props.setActiveLanguage("es"); // Although Spanish was added first in the list of languages, I want to make sure the active language is Spanish
  }

  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <LocalizeProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
      </LocalizeProvider>
    );
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
   ...
};

export default withLocalize(Root);
```

Then, in a stateless controller named Header, I want to make use of the localize through the Translate component of the library.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Translate } from "react-localize-redux";

const Header = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="header-container">
...
...
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li className="menu-item"> 
                               <a href="#one-page-home">
                                    <Translate id="header.home" />
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
...
...
        </div>
    );
};

Header.propTypes = {
    ...
};

export default Header;
```

I'm getting the error: `Missing TranslationId: header.home for language: ${ languagecode }`

I've followed the documentation but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any help? Something wrong that a more versed user of this great library can see at a first glance?

**`react` version 16.4.2 and `react-localize-redux` version 3.4.1**

Comment: im having the same problem now:(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, at least was my case, I didn't wrap the whole render with `<LocalizeProvider>`

```
ReactDom.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <LocalizeProvider initialize={{
        languages: [
        { name: "English", code: "en" },
        { name: "Spanish", code: "es" }
        ],
        translation: { home: ['hello', 'alo'] },
        options: {
        defaultLanguage: "en",
            renderToStaticMarkup: renderToStaticMarkup
        }
    }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" children={(props) => <Login {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" children={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path="/" children={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </LocalizeProvider>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Instead of this:

```
ReactDom.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <LocalizeProvider initialize={{
        languages: [
        { name: "English", code: "en" },
        { name: "Spanish", code: "es" }
        ],
        translation: { home: ['hello', 'alo'] },
        options: {
        defaultLanguage: "en",
            renderToStaticMarkup: renderToStaticMarkup
        }
    }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" children={(props) => <Login {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" children={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path="/" children={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </LocalizeProvider>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```